# How to save the user's email recipients when sending email with UIActivityViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using UIActivityViewController and when the user selects email from the list of options is there a way to save the email recipients that the user inputs?

Do I need to subclass ActivityItemSource as was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623260/how-do-i-set-recipients-for-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-ios-6?rq=1)?

I realize getting the email recipients is tricky even with just using MFMailcomposeViewController as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985140/getting-the-recepients-list-in-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller).

Do I need to subclass MFMailcomposeViewController to save the email recipients that the user inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Important**: The mail composition interface itself is not customizable
>   and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after
>   presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make
>   further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the
>   content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored.
>   Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the
>   interface.

So, no.  You should not subclass `MFMailcomposeViewController` in order to "steal" the email addresses that the user has entered.  This is a privacy issue, and Apple specifically designed it this way.  If you try to circumvent this, then your app very likely will be (and should be) rejected.

Comment: Inafziger, thank you for your answer.  I'm sorry that you inferred nefarious "stealing" without knowing the context.   The context is that the user willingly enters an email address in exchange for a reward.  I just need to capture that email address.  I've now thought of another way to do so.

Comment: Well, I did put it in quotes, mainly to infer that it COULD be used for that purpose (and therefore explains why it can't/shouldn't be done).  Sorry if you took it as a personal affront as it certainly wasn't meant that way!